# Convert XML namespaces to top level prefixes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

Using XSLT, I would like to beautify my XML and pull up the namespace declarations and use prefixes instead.

I got:

```
<a xmlns="ns1">
    <b xmlns="ns2">
        <c xmlns="ns3"/>
    </b>
</a>
```

I want:

```
<a xmlns="ns1" xmlns:b="ns2" xmlns:c="ns3">
    <b:b>
        <c:c/>
    </b:b>
</a>
```

Doing this in one step automatically will be difficult. So I thought about multiple steps. One for each namespace.

I tried to use `namespace="{namespace-uri(.)}"` but I was not able to pull the namespace up to the root element.

Comment: How do you want to determine which prefixes to use?

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be any clear logic in your choice of namespace prefixes in your example, so I think that will be hard to achieve, but here is how to do something similar:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
                exclude-result-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kNs" match="*[namespace-uri()]" use="namespace-uri()" />

  <!-- Build a list of elements to represent all namespaces -->
  <xsl:variable name="uniqueNsNf">
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[generate-id() = 
                              generate-id(key('kNs', namespace-uri())[1])]">
      <xsl:element name="ns{position()}:ns" namespace="{namespace-uri()}" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="uniqueNs" select="exslt:node-set($uniqueNsNf)/*" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()]">
    <xsl:variable name="nsMap" 
                  select="$uniqueNs[namespace-uri() = 
                                    namespace-uri(current())]" />
    <xsl:element name="{substring-before(name($nsMap), ':')}:{local-name()}" 
                 namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$uniqueNs/namespace::*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on the following input:

```
<a xmlns="ns1">
  <b xmlns="ns2">
    <c xmlns="ns3"/>
    <b xmlns="ns2" />
  </b>

  <d xmlns="otherNs">
    <b xmlns="ns3" />
  </d>
</a>
```

The result is:

```
<ns1:a xmlns:ns1="ns1" xmlns:ns2="ns2" xmlns:ns3="ns3" xmlns:ns4="otherNs">
  <ns2:b>
    <ns3:c />
    <ns2:b />
  </ns2:b>

  <ns4:d>
    <ns3:b />
  </ns4:d>
</ns1:a>
```